# Need assistance with cleaning words that were counted from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input text file from which I have to count sum of characters, sum of lines, and sum of each word.

So far I have been able to get the count of characters, lines and words. I also converted the text to all lower case so I don't get 2 different counts for same word where one is in lower case and the other is in upper case.

Now looking at the output I realized that, the count of words is not as clean. I have been struggling to output clean data where it does not count any special characters, and also when counting words not to include a period or a comma at the end of it.

```
Ex. if the text file contains the line: "Hello, I am Bob. Hello to Bob *"

it should output:
2 Hello
2 Bob
1 I
1 am
1 to

Instead my code outputs
1 Hello,
1 Hello
1 Bob.
1 Bob
1 I
1 am
1 to
1 *
```

Below is the code I have as of now.

```
# Open the input file
fname = open('2013_honda_accord.txt', 'r').read()

# COUNT CHARACTERS
num_chars = len(fname)

# COUNT LINES 
num_lines = fname.count('\n')

#COUNT WORDS
fname = fname.lower() # convert the text to lower first
words = fname.split()
d = {}
for w in words:
    # if the word is repeated - start count
    if w in d:    
       d[w] += 1
    # if the word is only used once then give it a count of 1
    else:
       d[w] = 1

# Add the sum of all the repeated words 
num_words = sum(d[w] for w in d)

lst = [(d[w], w) for w in d]
# sort the list of words in alpha for the same count 
lst.sort()
# list word count from greatest to lowest (will also show the sort in reserve order Z-A)
lst.reverse()

# output the total number of characters
print('Your input file has characters = ' + str(num_chars))
# output the total number of lines
print('Your input file has num_lines = ' + str(num_lines))
# output the total number of words
print('Your input file has num_words = ' + str(num_words))

print('\n The 30 most frequent words are \n')

# print the number of words as a count from the text file with the sum of each word used within the text
i = 1
for count, word in lst[:10000]:
print('%2s.  %4s %s' % (i, count, word))
i += 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that after `.` , `,` ,`!` and `?` there is a white space? (except for the end of string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
words = fname.split()
```

With

```
get_alphabetical_characters = lambda word: "".join([char if char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' else '' for char in word])
words = list(map(get_alphabetical_characters, fname.split()))
```

Let me explain the various parts of the code.

Starting with the first line, whenever you have a declaration of the form

```
function_name = lambda argument1, argument2, ..., argumentN: some_python_expression
```

What you're looking at is the definition of a function that doesn't have any side effects, meaning it can't change the value of variables, it can only return a value.

So `get_alphabetical_characters` is a function that we know due to the suggestive name, that it takes a word and returns only the alphabetical characters contained within it.

This is accomplished using the `"".join(some_list)` idiom which takes a list of strings and concatenates them (in other words, it producing a single string by joining them together in the given order).

And the `some_list` here is provided by the generator expression `[char if char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' else '' for char in word]`

What this does is it steps through every character in the given word, and puts it into the list if it's alphebetical, or if it isn't it puts a blank string in it's place.

For example

```
[char if char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz' else '' for char in "hello."]
```

Evaluates to the following list:

```
['h','e','l','l','o','']
```

Which is then evaluates by

```
"".join(['h','e','l','l','o',''])
```

Which is equivalent to

```
'h'+'e'+'l'+'l'+'o'+''
```

Notice that the blank string added at the end will not have any effect. Adding a blank string to any string returns that same string again.
And this in turn ultimately yields

```
"hello"
```

Hope that's clear!

Edit #2: If you want to include periods used to mark decimal we can write a function like this:

```
include_char = lambda pos, a_string: a_string[pos].isalnum() or a_string[pos] == '.' and a_string[pos-1:pos].isdigit()
words = "".join(map(include_char, fname)).split()
```

What we're doing here is that the `include_char` function checks if a character is "alphanumeric" (i.e. is a letter or a digit) or that it's a period and that the character preceding it is numeric, and using this function to strip out all the characters in the string we want, and joining them into a single string, which we then separate into a list of strings using the `str.split` method.

Comment: You should write a complete answer explaining everything.

Comment: I would like to but I'm not sure what to explain. There is enough code here to dedicate paragraphs to - I'm new to answering questions about Python so I'm waiting for feedback from the question's author so I can get a good feel for what people generally do and do not need to have explained.

Comment: Edited to give an explanation of the most potentially confusing parts.

Comment: So I replaced as you suggested. It does not count the commas or the periods at the end). I also added numbers 0-9 in the exception because my text file contains numbers that I should count as well. The only issue I see now is that although it does not count the special character  but it counts it as a space. for example. I have 6 $ in the text file, though it ignores the $ it outputs 6 (blank). Also since its ignoring the periods there are some decimal numbers so the period is removed from the decimals which could be an issue.

Comment: Do you mean dollar-signs adjacent to other bits of text, as in `100$` or dollar-signs seperated on both sides by white-space as in `ABC $ EFG` ?

Comment: basically the text file has 6 bullet points, So the code is ignoring the count of each bullet but it outputs as space. I guess I could just remove the bullets points from the text file.

Comment: The only concern now would be the decimals.. would it be possible to not ignore the period if its part of a decimal?

Comment: I made an edit to the answer at the bottom which addresses the problem with decimal points. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This program may help you:

```
#I created a list of characters that I don't want \
# them to be considered as words!
char2remove = (".",",",";","!","?","*",":")
#Received an string of the user. 
string = raw_input("Enter your string: ")
#Make all the letters lower-case
string = string.lower()
#replace the special characters with white-space.
for char in char2remove:
    string = string.replace(char," ")
#Extract all the words in the new string (have repeats)
words = string.split(" ")
#creating a dictionary to remove repeats
to_count = dict()
for word in words:
    to_count[word]=0
#counting the word repeats. 
for word in to_count:
    #if there is space in a word, it is white-space!
    if word.isalpha():
        print word, string.count(word)
```

Works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter your string: Hello, I am Bob. Hello to Bob *
i 1
am 1
to 1
bob 2
hello 2
>>>
```

---

Another way is using Regex to remove all non-letter chars (to get rid off `char2remove` list):

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')

your_str = raw_input("Enter String: ")
your_str = your_str.lower()
regex.sub(' ', your_str)

words = your_str.split(" ")
to_count = dict()
for word in words:
    to_count[word]=0

for word in to_count:
    if word.isalpha():
        print word, your_str.count(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I sort it and output the count of words from highest to lowest order?